# Proper Way To Use Single Sign On And Avoid Extra Dialog (Android)

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

When I log into FB through my Android app, I provide the last valid auth key and expiration date to the Facebook object (created less than 5 minutes before), expecting to be logged in.

Instead, I get a dialog stating that "You have already authorized this app". This is obviously a bad user experience, and I'd like to do what I can to just let the user log in without this.

My flow for logging in is to

- Set the last valid auth key and expiration
- Call authorize()
- On success, I sent this auth key to the server, which verifies that the key is valid with the FB graph API.

Here's a reduction of how I'm calling this:

```
Facebook m_facebook;
int ACTIVITY_CODE_FACEBOOK_AUTH = 1;
// auth key and expiration are set from a previous login
m_facebook.setAccessToken(accessToken);
m_facebook.setAccessExpires(expirationTime);
// permissions contains publish_stream, publish_actions, email and does not change.
m_facebook.authorize(m_activity, permissions, ACTIVITY_CODE_FACEBOOK_AUTH, new AppLoginListener());
```

A possible workaround would be to first call the Graph API with the auth key to ensure that it's valid. If it isn't valid, call authorize() as above. If it is valid, just pretend we called authorize and carry on. This feels like a hack, and I'd think I should just be able to authorize() (and use SSO) without making any sistered Graph API workarounds.

- I'm using the FB SDK rom 2012/4/4. There don't appear to be any relevant changes since then.
- I've seen questions similar to this from a year ago, but I haven't seen concrete answers that solve my problem, nor do the solutions seem different from what I'm already doing.

Comment: I believe that this flow may have been changed by FB recently.  I had the same approach as you and I believe that the "you have already authorized this app" screen is new in the past week or two.  Hopefully someone else can clarify.

Comment: Can you post the code you use for authentication and the part that results in "You have already authorized this app"?

Comment: I've added in the important bits of the code I'm calling, above.

Comment: good luck fixing this with your flow ;)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if the flow has changed recently to be honest, all I can say is I am using it differently and this works for me.

- check if a authorisation token even exists (I store mine in preferences)
- check if it is still valid
- only if one of both conditions isn't met, there is the need to authorise (again)

  ```
  private SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("APP_Preferences", MODE_PRIVATE); 
  Facebook facebook = new Facebook("app_number");

  if (!facebook.isSessionValid() || !prefs.contains("fb_access_token")){
      loginToFacebook();              
  }else{
      //do something else
  }
  ```

Also, I make sure the token is extended in the background so a valid token is available pretty much all the time by calling:

```
    facebook.extendAccessTokenIfNeeded(context, null);
```

in a background service of my app. This makes sure that even if the user doesn't open my app for days, the token is valid and current all the time, so no annoying authorisation requests will happen when the user does open the app after a while. I think this flow will help you with your problem.

I am using a service in the application for other more logical purposes anyway, so I can do this as a added benefi, but it would probably not be a good idea to implement a service in your app just to extend the token...

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, there is simply something wrong with the flow in the OP's Q. Why explicitly call the `authorise()` method, this will show exactly the dialog the OP is complaining about? If you're logged in, you're logged in (unless access is revoked, but this is another issue).

Comment: There's probably another problem, but this issue will not be resolved until the flow is fixed. If a valid session exists, why call `authorise()` again? Why not just request data? I noticed when testing however, when reinstalling an already authorised app, the dialog OP mentions is shown, but that actually makes sense and is not described in the Q. The real problem here seems to be the flow.